# Are multiple functions in one .m file nested or local when "end" isn't used

Tags: matlab, function, nested-function

In MATLAB you can have multiple functions in one `.m` file. There is of course the main function, and then either [nested or local functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html).

Examples of each function type:

```
% myfunc.m with local function ------------------------------------------
function myfunc()
    disp(mylocalfunc());
end
function output = mylocalfunc()
    % local function, no visibility of variables local to myfunc()
    output = 'hello world';
end
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

% myfunc.m with nested function -----------------------------------------
function myfunc()
    disp(mynestedfunc());
    function output = mynestedfunc()
        % nested function, has visibility of variables local to myfunc()
        output = 'hello world';
    end
end
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The difference is clear when you use the functions' `end` statements. However, I don't think it's clearly documented which you are using when you don't, since this is valid syntax:

```
% myfunc.m with some other function 
function myfunc()
    disp(myotherfunc());
function output = myotherfunc()
    % It's not immediately clear whether this is nested or local!
    output = 'hello world';
```

**Is there any clear definition of whether functions written like `myotherfunc` are local or nested?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be quickly tested because of the variable scope differences [mentioned in the documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html)

> The primary difference between nested functions and local functions is that **nested functions can use variables defined in parent functions** without explicitly passing those variables as arguments.

So adapting the question example:

```
function myfunc()
    % Define some variable 'str' inside the scope of myfunc()
    str = 'hello world';
    disp(myotherfunc());
function output = myotherfunc()
    % This gives an error because myotherfunc() has no visibility of 'str'!
    output = str;
```

This errors because **`myotherfunc` is in fact a local function**, not a nested function.

The test is supported by the [documentation for nested functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) which states:

> Typically, functions do not require an `end` statement. However, **to nest *any* function in a program file, *all* functions in that file must use an `end`** statement.