# How to end MATLAB/Octave function definitions?

Tags: matlab, function, syntax, scripting, octave

When looking for snippets of code for MATLAB and Octave I noticed that functions are ended in various ways, and all of them seem to work just fine. To be specific, I am talking about functions residing in their specific file.

[MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) seems to end their functions with `end`.

```
function y = average(x)
  y = sum(x)/length(x); 
end
```

[Octave](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Defining-Functions.html) ends its functions with `endfunction`.

```
function retval = avg (v)
  retval = sum (v) / length (v);
endfunction
```

However, my functions work perfectly fine without any keyword at the end of the function.

So my question is, how strict are MATLAB/Octave with the endings of function definitions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### `endfunction`

- `endfunction` is Octave-specific, and not valid MATLAB syntax (the same goes for `endfor` etc...)
- If you know the code is only ever going to be run in Octave, then this syntax can make matching-up your loops/functions/... clearer and quicker. Just be aware your code is then MATLAB incompatible.
- I believe you can also just use `end` in Octave for compatibility.

### Strictness of using `end`

You may want to read the [MATLAB documentation for nested functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)

- You don't have to end a function with the `end` statement when it is the only function in a file. From the docs:

  > Typically, functions do not require an end statement.
- Here is a related question on SO: [Are multiple functions in one .m file nested or local when "end" isn't used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200119/are-multiple-functions-in-one-m-file-nested-or-local-when-end-isnt-used), with the relevant excerpt being this, also from the docs:

  > To nest any function in a program file, all functions in that file must use an end statement.

So in a function file with a sole function, the short answer is "not strict at all". However, it's good practise to use `end` so there is less ambiguity and more flexibility if you were to add other local functions.

Comment: Octave does allow to use simple `end` instead of the specific `endX`

Comment: Fair enough, but I find the current wording in this answer slightly misleading.  "ends" are optional in any function file definitions, not just files with single functions.

Comment: @John I'm not sure if what you say is true for subfunctions, but it's highly unlikely to be true for nested functions. And, either way, it's much clearer to denote the end of your function anyway.

Comment: @Tasos sub/nested functions are covered in this answer