# Unit testing with file-wide variables, without classes

Tags: matlab

Suppose, for whatever reason, I refuse to use `matlab.unittest.TestCase`. I seek to reproduce the following Python functionality:

```py
# `utils.py` is in same directory as the test file
# `test_wide_variable` gets used inside or outside of test functions
from utils import test_wide_variable

# gets used inside of test functions
file_wide_variable = [1, 2, 3]

def test_func1():
    y = (file_wide_variable, test_wide_variable)
    # ...

# ...

test_func1()
# test_func2()
test_func3()
# ...
```

#### Attempt

Define `reset_test_params.m`, with

```matlab
global P
P = struct;
```

Then, the test file looks like

```matlab
reset_test_params

P.file_wide_variable = [1, 2, 3];
P.test_wide_variable = load('test_wide_variables.m').test_wide_variable;

test_func1()
% test_func2()
test_func3()
% ...

function test_func1(~)
    global P
    y = {P.file_wide_variable, P.test_wide_variable};
    % ...

% ...
```

#### Question

Any notable downsides with this approach? In particular, concurrent file execution? With Python one can run multiple tests at once in same global namespace (AFAIK), so a global variable would be a no-no.

Comment: Are you intending to use function-based unittests, in which case stuff here might help: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-test-using-setup-and-teardown-functions.html ?

Comment: Also, are the specific reasons why you don't wish to / can't use `TestCase`?

Comment: Yes, function-based unittests. I'm against `TestCase` due to adding two indent tabs, and inability to select individual tests I wish to run easily (my approach is to write out all `test_*` calls manually, so I can comment them out, and "go-to" them easily). I may be misunderstanding the tabs stuff, but it's still not pretty. It's also a learning overhead. Some Python functionality enabled by permitting in-file declarations is also harder to reproduce. The only dealbreaker is inability to select tests.

Comment: `test_func` is local to your script, but you don’t call it in the script. You cannot call it from anywhere else. Anyway, why does `P` need to be global? You’re resetting it at the start of each test script, so why not make it a local variable? If `test_func` is a nested function, it can use the parent’s variables. But also, why can’t you simply pass the data into the function normally?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have several functions per script. Global because it won't let me do `P = ` in the file. ... or so I thought? I recall having an issue with it, but now it runs - still won't recognize it inside of test functions unless I declare it as `global` in the file, but sure, that's one way to no longer need `reset_test_params.m`. Why not pass in - well, that's not how test parameters are meant to be handled? Not in Python, and from docs it seems not in MATLAB either - it's clumsy and the number of configs may change, and I don't see how it absolves the Q's problem in any way.

Comment: Depending [how you nest your functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46200125/3978545) a local variable would be visible to functions in the same script without being global

Comment: @CrisLuengo [re: pre-last comment] Yes, but these don't describe why my proposed approach is bad. I don't seek to reproduce _all_ Python functionality equivalently. -- _"never call scripts from other scripts"_ sounds similar to Python's "never use `eval()`" - what specific issue do you imagine with using a script to re-initialize global variables?

Comment: The test browser https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-tests-using-test-browser.html lets you run individual test points in a class-based test. As does `runtests(..., Name="...")`. (I use the latter *all the time*).

Comment: @Edric Looks like a bit more work than commenting unwanted funcs, and doesn't solve the "go-to", but good to know! MATLAB certainly one-ups Python on built-in profiling GUI, seems to be also for unit testing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo _(ans-cont'd)_ [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwrFG.png) -- [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVm5e.png) -- works dandy! Even with `runtests('UseParallel', true)` (though unsure about that yet), with coverage also. [Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqrbR.png). All runs with a single `runtests`, so dunno what the "runner file"'s for, maybe classes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I’m rather disappointed though. You come here asking for advice, everyone tells you not to do it that way, we put in the effort to help you with better approaches, and then you do it your way anyway. I seem to have wasted time here. All I can say is that I hope your code is not intended to ever be maintained by someone else, because you’re not making it easy on them. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I read everyone's writing and consider it seriously. But I listen only to reason, and I remain unconvinced that this is a significant issue. Programmers often have certain habits that are nothing but quirks which they masquerade as good advice, so a default distrust from me. It will indeed be maintained by someone, and I do ask whether they're okay with this approach - the "Details" URL omits the last line where I ask whether it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I just learned that you do use the builtin test harness `runtests`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77206580/7328782). Other details were also not clear when I wrote the answer below the break. So here is my recommendation to avoid globals:

All you need to do is start your file with `function <name>`, and end it with an `end`. This turns all the test functions inside into nested functions, as explained below. Now remove all mentions of the keyword `global`, and things should work as you expect them to work, using file-wide variables shared among the test functions in your file but not across files.

I still strongly recommend not calling a script from within code, some of the dangers are described below. It is no effort whatsoever to turn that into a function that returns the constant data.

---

### Original answer:

Your Python script, let's call it `my_tests.py`,

```py
from utils import test_wide_variable

# gets used inside of test functions
file_wide_variable = [1, 2, 3]

def test_func():
    y = (file_wide_variable, test_wide_variable)
    # ...
```

presumably gets called by the test harness with

```py
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

import my_tests
for name, func in getmembers(my_tests, isfunction):
   func()
```

or something similar (I haven't even tested this code).

Your MATLAB script, let's call it `my_tests.m`,

```matlab
reset_test_params

P.file_wide_variable = [1, 2, 3];
P.test_wide_variable = load('test_wide_variables.m').test_wide_variable;

function test_func(~)
    global P
    y = {P.file_wide_variable, P.test_wide_variable};
    # ...
```

when called in a test harness,

```matlab
my_tests
```

or equivalently

```matlab
run("my_tests")
```

will cause `P` to be defined in the test harness's workspace (hopefully not overwriting any local variables!). `test_func()`, however, is lost. The script itself doesn't call it, so it remains unused and undefined. Being a local function, it can only be called from within `my_tests.m`.

So, attempting to directly replicate Python's format for a test script is a non-starter, because the two languages work fundamentally differently in these respects.

---

Note also that, when you call a script from within another script or function (in MATLAB), all of its variables will be defined in the caller's workspace. This means that the script can potentially overwrite any of the caller's variables. Using scripts to build a more complex piece of software is a really bad idea, it would be a nightmare trying to keep all of your script's variables separate. This is exactly what functions are for. Functions have a local scope, making composition a lot easier.

I would not use scripts for anything other than (maybe) the program's entry point. Everything else should be a function. There is no reason not to use functions.

---

This is how I would attempt to reproduce the Python format in MATLAB:

`test_wide_variable.m`:

```matlab
function v = test_wide_variable
v = [5, 6, 7];
```

`my_tests.m`:

```matlab
function funcs = my_tests
   file_wide_variable = [1, 2, 3];
   data = test_wide_variable

   funcs = {@test_func};  % list all the test functions defined in the file

   function test_func
      y = {file_wide_variable, data};
      % ...
   end

end
```

Now this could be called from a test harness as follows:

```matlab
fail = 0
total = 0
for func = my_tests
   total = total + 1;
   try
      func()
   catch ME
      disp(ME)
      fail = fail + 1;
   end
end
disp(fail + "tests failed out of " + total " tests.")
```

Note that the variables declared locally in the function `my_tests()` are available to the nested functions defined within this function (note that these functions are declared between the `function` and the `end` statements for `my_tests()`, and so [they are nested functions, not local functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/types-of-functions.html#btg5k9l).

The `my_tests()` function returns a cell array with handles to the nested functions. These can then be called by the calling test harness. When called, they still have access to the variables defined in `my_tests` as they were when the function handles were first obtained -- these are lambda captures.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I have no idea how you're using that script, you're not specifying it. But it's a script, there's only one way to run it.

Comment: Ok, that's definitely a working alternative. Though I'm quite uneasy about having all the functions exist in a limbo before the script is ran, maybe that's just a Python thing. Adding one indent is certainly an issue, but I guess I can just refuse to do that? More importantly, so far I thought nested functions aren't even valid in MATLAB, I wonder why? I didn't just come up with it... and would there be performance issues? I have a test file that's 3000 lines long with in Python, with 23 tests, it'll probably be 4-5000 in MATLAB (I'm aware that's generally undesired).

Comment: and from what I've read, it appears that my approach is indeed fine. It's only a few variables that will be re-emptied with each test run, I'm not normalizing using scripts as function calls.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I don't know how you call the functions in your approach... unless you're using Octave. In MATLAB you cannot call them, they're only defined within the script at the top of the file where they're defined.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD0Pr.png

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon You don't need  to indent. I indented to make it obvious we're using nested and not local functions here, but it's totally fine to not use indents. I don't think there's any performance issues. And the functions certainly don't "exist in limbo", they're defined and you're holding on to handles to them so you can reference them later.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon That screen shot you just posted: that's not what you show in the question. Yes, you can call the functions within the script. But if you make the script a function (with the tests being local functions) you accomplish exactly the same thing, but without using scripts.

Comment: Does that mean I'd have to have another file to actually execute the functions? That's a no-no! And I didn't think that mattered much (your first sentence), but it makes sense, thanks, I'll update

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon In Python there's also a separate program that runs the tests. The advantage is that it collects common stuff to do across tests (`try`/`catch` block and so on) and counts the tests performed and failed. See my edited test harness code, it is more representative. Anyway, that's the "run my tests" program, which you'll need if you don't want to run each test manually.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Also, the idea with those tests scripts in Python, and which you should copy, is that you can define many files each with many tests. But you can sort tests into files by topic or whatever, and you can keep each test file relatively short. A 3000 line long bit of source code is not convenient.

Comment: The idea's to be able to run individual tests, what you propose appears to require running all test files at the same time. But I don't see why we can't just call `my_tests()` at top of `my_tests.m` (just change file name)? And your Python descriptions aren't quite accurate, we can run both per-file and globally using a unittest framework, I do it both in Spyder and in remote builds (Github Actions / Travis CI), without a "master runner file". If I need said file in MATLAB, seems I can make it work with my approach also.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon "we can run both per-file and globally using a unittest framework" Yes. And it has lots of conveniences because it's a pre-made system. You're choosing to roll your own in MATLAB instead of using the built-in unit testing system, so you'll have to recreate that framework. The test harness is a program that either runs all tests, or runs the subset of tests you want to run, or runs the one test you want to run. You'd have to write that logic yourself though. In Python your "master runner file" is the `pytest` program or whatever framework you're using.

Comment: hmm well that's an important caveat of https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-test-using-setup-and-teardown-functions.html that I've not seen written anywhere (not that I've read a lot)... but I figure it won't be hard, just fetch all files and functions within said files. Am I right about being able to run your approach in one file (prev comment)? -- _""master runner file" is `pytest`"_ no? Well, maybe Spyder and remote builds do something behind the scenes that I'm not aware of, but I don't have to manually code any special runner file.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Yes, you can do my approach in one file. It'll look like yours but without global variables. `my_tests()` would be a local function that calls all of its nested functions directly, and the main function in the file would just call `my_tests()`. "I don't have to manually code any special runner file." No, it's already written for you. But again, you're rolling your own instead of using the built-in functionality, so you have to write it yourself. MATLAB already has a function like that, but it requires you write your tests in a different way that you don't like.

Comment: _"the main function in the file would just call `my_tests()`"_ isn't `my_tests` the "main function"? What else do I need? I'd think I'd just put `my_tests()` on top of the script and that's it. Anyway, OK, this clarifies all my concerns and-some, thanks.