# Does MATLAB's UseParallel use a shared namespace?

Tags: matlab

[`runtests`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/runtests.html) runs tests, and its `'UseParallel', true` runs them in parallel. In Python, I've had trouble with a shared namespace when running tests in parallel - how's MATLAB?

I carefully use global variables which are reset at start of each test:

```matlab
% reset_test_params.m
global P
P = struct;
```

so `reset_test_params` is at top of each test. If `test_file1.m` sets `P.factor = 1` while default is `P.factor = 2`, does `test_file2.m` risk reading `P.factor` that's `1`? In fact I've not even used globals in Python and still had clashes, import-related I think.

Are there risks of namespace contamination with `'UseParallel', true`, via globals or otherwise?

Comment: I guess this depends on how you build your parallel pool. Obviously globals are not shared among MATLAB instances on different nodes, and apparently also not shared among separate MATLAB instances. But they probably are shared in a thread-based parallel pool. The only way to know for sure is to test, because it’s a closed system. There are lots of questions about parallelism and globals on MATLAB Answers, but I haven’t seen any information about the newer thread-based pools. But luckily [you already have an alternative that doesn’t need globals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77181034/7328782).

Comment: If everyone with experience tells you not to use globals if you don’t really need them, then you can either learn from their experience or make the same mistakes and learn on your own. There are thousands of pieces of text online about why globals are problematic, this is true in every single programming language out there. Because it’s the concept itself that is problematic. Of course there are times when a global is the right solution, but these times are rare. If there is a simple alternative, use it!

Comment: Actually, if someone as experienced and elaborate-willing as you is failing to convince me, I take it as strong evidence that it's indeed nothing to worry about. -- Thanks re: parallelism - my concern with testing myself is that the issue might be intermittent, and setting up a sufficiently robust test and running it enough times takes time, so I tried my shot here. Also awaiting MathWorks feedback.